# присваивание значений переменной

Tags: c

Код на си:

```
num = (num *= s, i = num, num -= i);
```

не понимаю как тут присваиваются значения. помогите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
num = (num *= s, i = num, num -= i);
```

В скобках использован оператор "запятая, т.е. выполняются поочередно опетаторы

```
num *= s;
i = num;
num -= i;
```

и возвращается значение последнего оператора, т.е. `num`. Т.е. выполняется присваивание

```
num = num;
```

Впрочем, очевидно, что `num` будет 0 для любых значений, так что все, что делает этот код, можно записать как

```
i = num*s;
num = 0;
```

Comment: А если код в цикле, и `n` в нем более не меняется, то начиная со второй итерации получим `num = i = 0;`